# finding count using aggregate function sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

For the given data i need to find out count of id where salary is less than avg(salary)

```
id  salary
1   11
2   12 
2   14
1   12
1   13
1   14
1   15
```

So my final output will be like this

```
id count 
  1   2
  2   1
```

[avg salary of id 1 is 13 and avg salary of id 2 is 13. So there are two values in id 1 which are less than average salary of id similarly for id 2]

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? (you tagged it as both 11g and 10g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to use window functions for this:

```
select id, count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*, avg(salary) over (partition by id) as avgs
      from table t
     ) t
where salary < avgs
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY with COUNT(*) to count, check WHERE < AVG using sub-select:

```
select id, count(*)
from tablename
where salary < (select avg(salary) from tablename)
group by id
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select id , count(salary)
from tablename
group by id
having salary < avg(salary)
```

This query will give you count of salaries lesser than avg salary for each ID.
Hope you wanted this only.

Comment: because it errors with `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` on the "salary" in the having clause?

Comment: so need count(salary) in select?

Comment: no, you'd need to work out the average before you filter the rows. Ie. you can't do that just in the `having` clause, as that relates to the aggregated columns, and `salary` isn't one of those. Much like the other two proposed answers do.